# Does 100% pure avocado oil need special kosher l'Pesach certification?

Tags: halacha, passover, hechsher-certification, fruits, oil

Costco carries a brand of avocado oil that I think is produced by Whole Foods. I know that OU, and I think other kashrut agencies have stated that 100% pure olive oil needs no special Pesach certification.

Would avocado oil be in the same category? If not, how is the processing of avocado oil different from olive oil that requires certification whereas olive oil does not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a request for psak

Comment: related to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25976/is-extra-virgin-olive-oil-kosher-by-default

Comment: I called the OU certifying agency. No, it is not certified for passover.

Comment: @Daniel What about this question makes it a request for psak? This is a halacha question, but it's not asking for personal advice or a StackExchange-produced ruling.

Comment: @IsaacMoses well I think that the line between halacha questions and RFP is pretty fine, but since this question is about a very specific product, it seems more like a request for psak. I think it would be better to ask a more general question like "how does one determine whether a food product requires explicit Passover certification?"

Comment: @Daniel - It's already been voted up & down a few times, BTW. I'm not requesting personal advice, here. At this point, for me, I have the answer I want - mostly, so feel free to vote to close if you wish.

Comment: @Daniel If it can be answered sufficiently by referring to a published sefer or Pesach listing, it's not a request for pesak. The request for pesak version of this could be, "The OU says I can use avocado oil, and the Star K says I can't. Whom should I listen to?" or "No posekim have yet ruled on this question. How does Mi Yodeya rule?" Answering this question requires no personal details and no authority.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Hey! I LIKE the last version of the question ;-)